# How do I boot into recovery mode on an HTC Dream/G1?

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, htc-dream

I'm trying to revive and root an old HTC Dream. According to every ten-year-old tutorial I've been able to find, you should be able to boot into recovery mode by holding the Home + Power button as you boot the phone up. This simply doesn't work for me - the phone just boots up normally.

Is there anything else I can try? Does it differ for different specific HTC Dream models, or something?

It might be relevant that I've downgraded this phone down to Android 1/RC29 following tutorials. I've also noticed that the Call + Menu + Power combination to reboot the phone doesn't work, either.

Comment: adb (shell) reboot recovery or adb reboot bootloader and from bootloader menu select recovery maybe?

Comment: @alecxs Yup - since posting this question I found out about the `reboot recovery`, `reboot fastboot` etc family of commands. They don't work over ADB in my use-case, but they do work over the root telnet session (a long story, but anyone in the middle of trying to root an HTC dream will know what I'm talking about). I would love a clarification on why the keyboard commands don't work on my device, but I doubt anyone will know. I'll post an answer in a while.

Comment: maybe home button is not functional

Comment: Did you ever get root access on this device?

Answer (score 0):

1. Press the Power button to switch off the device.

   [image]
2. Press and hold the Home button + Power button at the same time.

   [image]
3. Keep holding the buttons until a black screen with a warning sign appears.

   [image]
4. Next, press ALT + L.

   [image]
5. Then Alt + W for 'wipe data/factory reset'.

   [image]
6. Press the Home + Back key.

   [image]
7. Device will restart and after that, you can use it.

   [image]

Comment: Appreciated the images, but looks like images 3 & 4 and 5 & 6 are the same?